# Function not defined using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

For some reason after I wrapped my js code in an immediately invoked function expression I'm getting `progressBar not defined`. Wondering why this is the case?

```
(function(){
    "use strict"

    var progressBar = function(){
        var bar = document.getElementById('pbar'),
        status = document.getElementById('status'),
        barValue = bar.value;

        status.innerHTML = barValue + "%";
        bar.value++;

        var increment = setTimeout("progressBar()", 50);
        if(bar.value == 100){
            status.innerHTML = '100% - Straight Besting';
            bar.value = '100';
            clearTimeout(increment);
        }
    }

    progressBar();

})()
```

Answer (score 6):

When you pass a string to `setTimeout`, it is invoked in the context of the global `window` object.

Change the `setTimeout` line to:

```
var increment = setTimeout(progressBar, 50);
```

E.g.

```js
(function() {
   let i = 0;
   let myfunction = function() {
      console.log(i++);
      if (i < 10) setTimeout(myfunction, 100);
   };

   myfunction();
})()
```

Comment: Thats interesting, why is that the case? Why when a function passed as a string into setTimout first arg, it is invoked in the context of the global not wihtin the scope?

Comment: It's because `setTimeout` is actually `window.setTimeout`. When you pass a string, you're actually passing in a string of "code" to execute, just like `eval`. The "code" does not contain any contextual information.